# compatibility of apps from phones to tablets

Tags: android, compatibility

I have an app that is compatible with my android phone (v 2.2.3) but not with my android tablet (v 4.0+). What can I do to make this app usable on my tablet? The app works on virtual device with settings similar to the real device. This app was created by someone else and he made it available for others to modify. The following is the manifest file...one of them.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="TaxiDriverMainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="EditOrderActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="ShiftHistoryActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TipHistoryActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="NewOrderActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TaxiSettingsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="DroppingOffActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="AddExpenseActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="ImmediatePickupAcitivty"></activity>
    <activity android:name="ShiftStartEndActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TaxiDriverMapActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="OdometerEntryActivity"></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"></uses-library>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: This will help you. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml